# right angle equal to obtuse triangle?

Tags: geometry, fake-proofs, angle

Given the obtuse angle x, we make a quadrilateral $ABCD$ with $∠DAB = x$, and $∠ABC = 90◦$, and $AD = BC$. Say the perpendicular bisector to $DC$ meets the perpendicular bisector to $AB$ at $Q$. Then $QA = QB$ and $QC = QD.$ So the triangles $QAD$ and $QBC$ have equal sides and are congruent. Thus $∠QAD = ∠QBC.$ But $QAB$ is isosceles, hence $∠QAB = ∠QBA.$ Subtracting, gives $x = ∠QAD−∠QAB = ∠QBC −∠QBA = 90◦$

When I draw out the actual figure, I find out that the proof falls at the last part; $QD$ will pass below A so $∠QAD$ does not equal to $x+∠QAB$ but I can't provide a formal prove of it. Some suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: This is really bad M.Chen, this question is from PROMYS application and it is clearly mentioned not to post these questions on any site. The questions in PROMYS are always reused and cannot be discussed. I hope moderators take a quick look.

Answer (score 1):

You argument *is* the proof you are looking for.  If $Q$ were situated such that $\angle QAD=\angle DAB+\angle QAB$, then your argument would be valid, and prove that $x$ is a right angle.  Since this conclusion is false, this is a proof by contradiction that $Q$ cannot be so situated.

Comment: oh thank you! Then can I just draw a figure and claim the proof is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have proven by contradiction that $Q$ can *NOT* be  in the interior of the quadrilateral becasuse if it were you would have proven the incorrect result that $x$ is right.

You'd get a similar result if $\angle DAB$ were accute.

If $\angle BAD$ is right then the quadrilateral is a recatangle and the bisectors are the same line and any interior point will do.

Otherwise if $\angle BAD$ is not right then the lines $DC$ and lines $AB$ are not parallel.  So the perp bisectors intersect.  You've proven they can't meet on the interior.  And the other hand you haven't proven whether the intersect above or below.